# Java dynamic web project error on startup

Tags: java, xml, startup

migrating from C++ to java so starting today wanted to follow some tutorials but, when I create new  dynamic web project, get error straight away in web.xml file. I installed java 11 se and downloaded java 8ee but not linked anywhere yet, also installed and linked tomcat 10.
[ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZBlW.png)

Could anyone know problem here?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
To get rid of first 5 errors change Java version to the installed on machine
To get rid of xml error, change  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee to
xmlns="http://Java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee make Java upper case